# Customized style support in PySide, how to cast QStyleOption to it's subclass?

Tags: c++, python, qt, pyside

```
class VisualStyle(QCleanlooksStyle):
    def drawControl(self, ce, opt, p, w):
        if ce == QStyle.CE_TabBarTabShape:
            print(opt.__class__) # opt is always the type 'PySide.QtGui.QStyleOption'
```

`qstyleoption_cast` seems not available in PySide. How can I cast `opt` to its subclass, i.e. `PySide.QtGui.QStyleOptionTab` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
myStyleOptionTab = QStyleOptionTab(opt)
```

Another example from the PySide docs:

```
def drawPrimitive(self, element, option, painter, widget):
    if element == self.PE_FrameFocusRect:
        focusRectOption =  QStyleOptionFocusRect(option)
        if focusRectOption:
            # ...
```

The PySide docs are somewhat garbled, because they are magically derived from the C++ docs? But usually the Python code in the examples is correct?

There is no "cast" notion in Python.  The notion of cast is for statically typed languages.  I'm not quite sure how to explain what PySide is doing with QStyleOption.  Anyway, creating an instance by calling the class (eg QStyleOptionTab(opt)) checks that the given instance is "the correct type" where the type is the C++ notion of type.  Or converts it from super class QStyleOption to the given subclass.

Comment: eventhough Python is a weakly typed language, it still supports casts and in fact is sometimes needed.

Comment: This doesn't work with PySide2, you will get this error:

```TypeError: 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QStyleOptionButton' called with wrong argument types:
      PySide2.QtWidgets.QStyleOptionButton(QStyleOption)
    Supported signatures:
      PySide2.QtWidgets.QStyleOptionButton()
      PySide2.QtWidgets.QStyleOptionButton(PySide2.QtWidgets.QStyleOptionButton)
      PySide2.QtWidgets.QStyleOptionButton(int)```

Obviously it's not wrapped properly

Answer (score 0):

found a little hack-style solution.

```
def drawPrimitive(self, element, option, painter, widget):
    if element == self.PE_FrameFocusRect:
        opt = QStyleOptionFocusRect()
        widget.initStyleOption(opt) # this is private, but python has no private methods ;)
```